# How to calculate second ODE in code from a previous ODE

Tags: python, ode

First, I will show you my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import scipy.integrate as integrate
from sympy import symbol

def acceleration(u, t):
  dudt = 3*pow(t,2)
  return dudt

t = np.linspace(0, 86400, 10) #time in s
u0 = 0 #velocity u for t = 0

u = odeint(acceleration, u0, t)

A = np.reshape(acceleration(u,t), (10,1))
print(A, u)

plt.xlabel('Time in s')
plt.ylabel('Velocity in m/s')
plt.plot(t, u)
plt.grid()
plt.show()

plt.xlabel('Time in s')
plt.ylabel('Acceleration in m/s^2')
plt.plot(t, A)
plt.grid()
plt.show()


def velocity(u, t):
   dxdt = u
   return dxdt
x0 = 0 #displacement for t = 0

x = odeint(velocity, x0, t)
print(x)

plt.xlabel('Time in s')
plt.ylabel('Displacement in m')
plt.plot(t, x)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

This is a program I'm trying to write to solve ODEs of basic physics problems (in this case displacement, velocity, acceleration). The code works up to the point of the second graph. When it tries to solve for x I get a matrix with 0 values and a graph with a straight line for x and it equals zero.

My question is this, how do I calculate the displacement formula x by integrating the velocity formula u ? I'm probably missing something that I don't know of, I tried to integrate u first via sympy symbol but jupyter gives back this error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'symbol' from 'sympy' (unknown location)
```

Thanks in advance for any answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your ODE is the following :

```
x''(t) = 3*t^2
```

Based on the example in the documentation for [odeint](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html), we need to decompose this ODE of second degree into two ODEs of first degree :

```
v'(t) = 3*t^2
x'(t) = v(t)
```

To solve this system using `odeint` the way you want, we need to pass ***the whole system*** to the function at once :

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint

# define the system
def acceleration(t):
    return 3*t**2

def system(u, t):
    v, x = u # split input variable
    dvdt = acceleration(t)
    dxdt = v 
    return [dvdt, dxdt]

# timeline
t = np.linspace(0, 86400, 10)  # time in s

# initial conditions
x0 = 0  # displacement for t = 0
v0 = 0  # velocity u for t = 0

# solve
sol = odeint(system, (v0, x0), t)
x = sol[:, 1]
v = sol[:, 0]
a = acceleration(t)

# plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(3, 1)

ax[0].set_xlabel('Time in s')
ax[0].set_ylabel('Acceleration in m/s^2')
ax[0].plot(t, a)
ax[0].grid()

ax[1].set_xlabel('Time in s')
ax[1].set_ylabel('Velocity in m/s')
ax[1].plot(t, v)
ax[1].grid()

ax[2].set_xlabel('Time in s')
ax[2].set_ylabel('Displacement in m')
ax[2].plot(t, x)
ax[2].grid()

plt.show()
```

---

**NOTE**: For newer code, scipy encourages the use of [`solve_ivp`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html#scipy.integrate.solve_ivp) rather than `odeint`.
The required changes to the code are minimal :

```py
def system(t, u): # invert `u` and `t` args
    v, x = u
    dvdt = acceleration(t)
    dxdt = v
    return [dvdt, dxdt]


# solve
t_span = t.min(), t.max()
sol = solve_ivp(system, t_span, (v0, x0), t_eval=t) # slightly different function call

# `sol` provides much more information than just the solution. Have a look at the docs for a full description
x = sol.y[1, :] 
v = sol.y[0, :]
a = acceleration()
``
```